# Storing NSFont to document

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Our picture editing cocoa application allows the user to add a string to a photo. This string has an associated NSFont object. We want to store this NSFont object in the saved document. Is using archiving NSFont using NSCoding the best way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought you would be better off storing an `NSFontDescriptor`, since that way you have more control over exactly which font you use when your editing app finds itself opening a file on a machine that doesn’t have the font that was used when the file was saved.